# What do I need to write to be able to communicate with a web service?

Tags: web-services, web, ide

I've been tasked (I'm not a web developer) with creating something (a web service "client") that will connect to a web service, retrieve a list of files (url's) and then download them (HTTP Post) for further processing.  I guess anything like a command line app that I can schedule to run daily will do (but I'm open to suggestions).

I have documentation for the web service, it uses SOAP 1.1 which I am somewhat familiar with (used it in a few web pages, but that was classic asp). They are even offering a WSDL to download in order to generate proxy classes, or you can create your own.

Below is the description of the objects that the WSDL creates:

There are six software entities that you will need to implement in your web service client.  If your development environment automatically generates these from the WSDL, they will have the following names and purposes:

1. DownloadSvc
2. Response
3. ResponseCodeEnum
4. UserType
5. CertificationEnum
6. FileFormat.

DownloadSvc Class – This is the central object you will use.  It implements the majority of the behavior needed to login to the service, to check the availability of a download and to obtain the download URL.  For example, it has a Login and a GetURLS method.  This class supports both full and change list (“delta”) downloads.

Response Class – Most methods of the DownloadSvc return this Response object.  The fields in Response are as follows:

1. The Response.code field always describes the success or failure of a method call.
2. The Response.value field sometimes contains additional information.The remaining four items are simple enumerations that define the allowable values in the fields passed from or to the service.

ResponseCodeEnum – Describes the possible values of the Response.code field.  For example, it may return a code of LoginOK or DownloadOK for successful calls, or an error-specific code for failures.  You can see the specific code values listed in the sample SOAP responses in the SOAP Appendix.

UserType – Only used with the Login method.  It identifies which password is being used to login: your Representative password or your Downloader password.

CertificationEnum – An enumeration that you use to certify your agreement with the FTC’s conditions for downloading these phone number files as specified on the download full or download change page.

FileFormat – An enumeration that lets you select a flat text file or an XML file format.

Here's my question: where do I start in Visual Studio? What type of project do I need? Thank you!

Comment: Go google a tutorial for creating a web services client in Visual studio.

Comment: If you can access a working web service I'd start with soapUI to learn how the service works then hit Visual Studio to build your client

Comment: add an IDE tag to your question (e.g. visual-studio-2010)

Comment: So I need a console application.. thanks!